SQLITE Database Initialization Issue - Android
App developer noob here.  I'm trying to build a simple .NET MAUI app using VS 2022 that has a SQLITE database as an embedded resource.  I'm using the sqlite-net-pcl package.
I have a repository called WitbitsRepository with this class:
public class WitbitsRepository
{
private SQLiteAsyncConnection db;
public WitbitsRepository()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("WitbitsRepository constructor called");
    var databasePath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "Witbits.db");
    Debug.WriteLine("Database path: " + databasePath);

    if (!File.Exists(databasePath))
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Database file not found at: " + databasePath);
        CopyDatabaseFromResource(databasePath);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Database file found at: " + databasePath);
    }
    db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(databasePath);

    CreateTablesAsync().Wait();
}
private async Task CreateTablesAsync()
{
    await db.CreateTableAsync<Book>();
}

My App.xaml.cs file has code to initialize the database before loading MainPage:
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeAppAsync();
    }

    private async void InitializeAppAsync()
    {
        await InitializeDatabaseAsync();
        MainPage = new MainPage();
    }

    private async Task InitializeDatabaseAsync()
    {
        var repository = new WitbitsRepository();
        await repository.InitializeDatabaseAsync();
    }
}

}
When I run the app in debug (Android Pixel 5) mode, the MainPage never loads.  What am I missing?
I put a button on the MainPage to check database connectivity, but the MainPage isn't even appearing.

If you put some breakpoints in that code and step through it, where does it block?

Using async void or .Wait() is usually a bad idea. Try and run async code after a constructor

Hans - you were right.  The .wait() was causing it to hang.  I've been able to get the database to copy successfully.  Thanks for your help.
